# Parsing "Static Analysis Results Interchange Format (SARIF)" in MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, static-code-analysis

When running various analyzers against a project using MSBuild all failures will be output in "Static Analysis Results Interchange Format (SARIF)" format (see eg. https://github.com/sarif-standard/sarif-spec). For instance a build may yield the following

```
{
  "version": "0.1",
  "toolInfo": {
    "toolName": "Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler",
    "productVersion": "1.1.0",
    "fileVersion": "1.1.0"
  },
  "issues": [
    {
      "ruleId": "SA1401",
      "locations": [
        {
          "analysisTarget": [
            {
              "uri": "C:\\SomeFile.cs",
              "region": {
                "startLine": 708,
                "startColumn": 30,
                "endLine": 708,
                "endColumn": 36
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "shortMessage": "Field must be private",
      "fullMessage": "A field within a C# class has an access modifier other than private.",
      "properties": {
        "severity": "Warning",
        "warningLevel": "1",
        "defaultSeverity": "Warning",
        "title": "Fields must be private",
        "category": "StyleCop.CSharp.MaintainabilityRules",
        "helpLink": "https:\/\/github.com\/DotNetAnalyzers\/StyleCopAnalyzers\/blob\/master\/documentation\/SA1401.md",
        "isEnabledByDefault": "True",
        "isSuppressedInSource": "True"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I would like to be able to parse the data above in the simplest way possible (and break the build if any non-suppressed issues are encountered). How to go about doing this?

PS. Preferably I would also like to avoid implementing my own MSBuild tasks and installing specific software (eg. PowerShell 3.0 - ConvertFrom-Json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there apparently is no built-in way of doing this I ended up using an inline msbuild task (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd722601.aspx), defined as

```
<UsingTask TaskName="ParseUnsupressedAnalysisIssues" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup>
        <Files ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Required="true" />
        <Result ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
        <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
        <Using Namespace="System"/>
        <Using Namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <Using Namespace="System.IO"/>
        <Using Namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <Using Namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization.Json"/>
        <Using Namespace="System.Xml"/>
        <Using Namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
            <![CDATA[
            List<TaskItem> taskItems = new List<TaskItem>();
            foreach(ITaskItem item in Files)
            {
                try
                {
                    string path = item.GetMetadata("FullPath");
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
                    using (XmlDictionaryReader reader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(fs, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
                    {
                        XElement doc = XElement.Load(reader);
                        XElement issuesRoot = doc.Elements("issues").SingleOrDefault();
                        List<XElement> unsupressedIssues = issuesRoot.Elements("item").Where(e => !"True".Equals((string)e.Element("properties").Element("isSuppressedInSource"), StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToList();
                        string unsupressedIssuesString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, unsupressedIssues);
                        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(unsupressedIssuesString))
                        {
                            taskItems.Add(new TaskItem(item.ItemSpec));
                            Console.WriteLine(unsupressedIssuesString);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    taskItems.Add(new TaskItem(item.ItemSpec));
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }

            Result = taskItems.ToArray();
            ]]>
        </Code>
    </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

which can then be invoked as

```
<ParseUnsupressedAnalysisIssues Files="@(AnalyzerFiles)">
    <Output ItemName="FailedAnalyzerFiles" TaskParameter="Result" />
</ParseUnsupressedAnalysisIssues>
<Error Text="FxCopAll: Following assemblies had analyzer errors @(FailedAnalyzerFiles)" Condition="'@(FailedAnalyzerFiles->Count())' &gt; 0" Code="2"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a SARIF SDK available to work with SARIF files. It's available as a [NuGet package Sarif.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sarif.Sdk/), and the source code is on GitHub in the Microsoft/sarif-sdk project, with a [How-To document](https://github.com/microsoft/sarif-sdk/blob/main/docs/how-to.md) that shows how to read a SARIF file from disk and deserialize it into a `SarifLog` object; then you can navigate through the SARIF object model to examine individual results.

In your case, you're interested in the `isSuppressedInSource` property in the result's “property bag.” The How-To document explains how you would retrieve that property:

```
Result result = …;

string isSuppressedInSource = result.GetProperty("isSuppressedInSource");
```

The SARIF spec is [available online](https://rawgit.com/sarif-standard/sarif-spec/master/Static%20Analysis%20Results%20Interchange%20Format%20(SARIF).html), and there's a [SARIF home page](http://sarifweb.azurewebsites.net) with links to more information.

Finally: be aware that the SARIF format changed significantly between Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and Update 3. The format is now at a stable 1.0.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Violations Command Line](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violations-command-line/) to parse the SARIF-file and give it the `-max-violations 0` parameter.

There are also tools for Jenkins and reporting violations to different Git services. Documented in [Violations Lib](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violations-lib).